# Upgrade from 10.5.8 to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, imac, upgrade, leopard

Is it possible for me with a 2007 iMac running Leopard (2.16 Ghz Intel 2 Duo and 2 GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM) to upgrade to Mountain Lion? If not, is there any later version I can upgrade to? If I can upgrade to Mountain Lion, do I need to install an earlier version first? And if so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

As pointed out by Kent, an iMac with a 2.16 Ghz Intel 2 Duo seems to be like an iMac (Late 2006) instead of an iMac (Mid 2007).

[Technical Specs for iMac (Late 2006)](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP28)

[Technical Specs for iMac (Late 2007)](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP16)

Therefore, you can only run Lion. Unfortunately, finding a legitimate copy of Lion could be a little tricky if you haven’t already purchased it. If you search for OS X Lion in the Mac App Store you’ll only find Mountain Lion, and Apple no longer sells an OS X Lion USB Thumb Drive (part number MD256Z/A) in its online store.
One of your options is to buy from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008SE504G) or another online retailer.

Or, get [Snow Leopard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001AMHWP8).

### Original Post

You have to install Snow Leopard first and then Mountain Lion.

### OS X Mountain Lion system requirements

To install Mountain Lion, you need one of these Macs:

```
**iMac (Mid 2007 or newer)** (Yours)
MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)
MacBook Pro (Mid/Late 2007 or newer)
MacBook Air (Late 2008 or newer)
Mac mini (Early 2009 or newer)
Mac Pro (Early 2008 or newer)
Xserve (Early 2009)
```

Your Mac needs:

```
OS X v10.6.8 or OS X Lion already installed
2 GB or more of memory
8 GB or more of available space
```

Your model must have a 64-bit EFI boot ROM.

An easy way to tell if you are running a K64 kernel is to use the uname command-line program. The "x86_64" in the excerpt below means that we are running a 64-bit kernel. If the output showed "i386" instead, that would mean a 32-bit kernel.

`uname -a Darwin... root:xnu-1456.1.25~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Therefore, you need to upgrade to Snow Leopard first.

### Other Things

AirDrop and AirPlay will **not** work on your computer.

### Sources

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5444

---

### Alternate Way

It is *possible*, but not necessarily legal, to install Mountain Lion over Leopard.

You can look at [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167868/how_to_install_mountain_lion_over_leopard.html).

Comment: In addition to AirDrop not working, AirPlay also will not.

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes uname gives: Darwin my-computer-1259.local 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

Comment: Your computer is running a 32-bit kernel. If your computer does not boot into the 64-bit kernel automatically you can force it to by restarting and holding down the "6" and "4" keys after the chime. Re-run the above command in Terminal. If you don't see "x86_64" then your model does not have a 64-bit EFI boot ROM and cannot boot Mountain Lion.

Comment: I think the 2.16GHz iMac is a late-2006 model; not mid-2007.

Comment: Kent, you are right. I just checked the Apple Support pages. Thank you for noticing; I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The cut-off for Mountain Lion compatibility is mid-2007 iMacs.  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5444

It looks like yours is before that (2.16 GHz was the last rev of white plastic models).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_(Intel-based)

You might be able to acquire a USB installer for 10.7 -- ([http://www.amazon.com/Apple-Mac-Lion-Thumb-Drive/dp/B0089FELB2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0089FELB2) for example) but, you will still have the same problems mentioned in sameetandpotatoes comment.