# Upgrade this iMac to the latest version of Os X?

Tags: macos, imac, upgrade

I have an iMac running 10.5.8. How well/badly do you think it would work if I upgrade to the most recent version of MacOsX (and can I leap there in one go, or do I need to first upgrade to an intermediate version of the operating system)?

Here is what System Profiler tells me:

```
   - Model Name: iMac
   - Model Identifier: iMac5,2
   - Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
   - Processor Speed: 1.83 GHz
   - Number Of Processors: 1
   - Total Number Of Cores: 2
   - L2 Cache: 2 MB
   - Memory: 2 GB
   - Bus Speed: 667 MHz
   - Boot ROM Version: IM52.0090.B09
   - SMC Version (system): 1.6f0
   - Serial Number (system): W86450CMWV7
   - Hardware UUID: 00000000-0000-1000-8000-0016CBA120C3
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Duplicate/Related question [Upgrade from 10.5.8 to Mountain Lion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99393/upgrade-from-10-5-8-to-mountain-lion/99395#99395). You have a late 2006, which **cannot run** Mountain Lion. See my answer on the link.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's site:

> If you’re running OS X Leopard and would like to upgrade to OS X Mountain Lion, first you’ll need to upgrade to OS X Snow Leopard. You can purchase OS X Snow Leopard [here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard).

Comment: That said, I don't think iMac 5,2 can run ML anyway. I'll have to verify that.

Answer (score 1):

Gonna be tight, if I was to upgrade to 10.8 on that, I would be looking to max the RAM out to whatever is supported (it's old RAM, shouldn't be at a premium for DDR2 yet), and I would also look to inserting an SSD as the boot disk.

Other than that, the CPU is just fine, it will never fly, but it's faster than my 1.6Ghz Core 2 Duo running in my MBA with 4Gb and an SSD.